# How to checkpoint a spark batch job like streaming

Tags: apache-spark, batch-processing

I'm writing a spark batch job which may fail during the course for execution. In case of failure, I would like it to process only unprocessed part. I'm familiar that such behaviour can be achieved in streaming application via checkpointing. Is there any such equivalent way of doing it for batch data processing?

I'm reading these large csv files from s3. I think, these files may be split into multiple partition, so keeping track of file name is not a viable solution. Is there any way to access the metadata what offset we are currently processing in the given file. I was thinking with this information, I might be able to greatly reduce the duplicate processing. Any suggestions/ workarounds (except stream processing)?

At this point of time, I do not have solution to achieve the expected outcome.

Comment: You can always provide a `uniqueId` column to your data and log that somewhere to figure out records causing exceptions.

Comment: This approach may introduce new constraints for data providers. Is there something I can do on the spark side, to get the internal metadata of the partition like which file, what offset it is processing , I can perhaps put then into say a object storage and use them later. Not sure how can I extract those lower level metadata into batch processing.

Comment: No, you can modify your streams on the fly. `stream.withColumn("randomInt", F.floor(F.rand() * very_large_number))`

Comment: when the job is rerun after failure, there is no guarantee that rows will get the same `randonInt` column in different runs.

Comment: If the error rates are frequent, you can always have a T joint in the stream, one outlet can be processed and other can be written to disk. Then replay from the disk to check if bug has been fixed or not.